# Setup Jenkins running on Linux to execute PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows-server-2008

How do you setup Jenkins running on Linux to execute a PowerShell script on a remote Windows Server 2008 without password prompt.

Master Jenkins on Linux / Slave on Windows. Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

Install an SSH server on the Windows server and use a public/private key pair for authentication. On Linux, you can then run

```
ssh -i <private key file> user@host "command"
```

to issue "command" on the server.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

A complete edit, since I couldn't get the previous answer working.

- Install Powershell for Linux: [Powershell on Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell);
- Write a powershell script:

> ```
> $username = "username"
> $secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
> $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username,$secpass)
> $remotepath = "c:\path\to\your.ps1"
>
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName windowscomputer -Credential $mycreds -FilePath $remotepath
> ```

- Now use Jenkins to execute a shell:

`powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass /path/to/your/local.ps1`

This is how I got it working eventually.

Comment: How is this related to the question? You don't seem to execute a remote command on a Windows machine.

Comment: The eventual idea is to run the command on a remote Windows machine, which is possible with powershell. Now just trying to get Jenkins and Powershell to get to work on Linux.